# Editing Hyperlinks for shapes

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, shapes

I have hundreds of shapes hyperlinked in numerous worksheets. The code below worked great to globally change the hyperlinks of all of these worksheets because I was only changing part of the hyperlink. How do I change these hyperlinks using a range of original hyperlinks (A2:A300), with a corresponding replacement range(B2:B300)?

```
Sub FixHyperlinks()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In Sheets
    Ws.Activate
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    sOld = "part of old address"
    sNew = "replacement to old address"
    For Each hl In wks.Hyperlinks
        hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, sOld, sNew)
    Next hl
 Next Ws
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don‘t understand your question. Do you have a list of 299 different old/new combinations of URLs? And you still want to change every hyperlink on every sheet?

Comment: Yes, I have new URL,s. I do not need to change every hyperlink on every sheet. I just need to change the hyperlinks that are in my A2:A300 list with a replacement from my B2:B300 list. For instance hyperlink in A2 would be replaced with a hyperlink in B2. A32 with B32 etc...

Comment: The A2:A300 hyperlinks are found on the existing shapes in the worksheets. The B2:B300 will be their replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Match` is able to find values in a list (range or array) and returns either an error or the position within that list.

If a hyperlink is found & changed, then the corresponding entry in column A becomes green text. If a hyperlink is not found, its worksheet's name and its address are shown in column C and D.

```
Sub FixHyperlinks()
    Dim listWS As Worksheet
    Dim currentWS As Worksheet
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    Dim foundRow As Variant
    Dim writeRow As Long

    Set listWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    writeRow = 2
    For Each currentWS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each hl In currentWS.Hyperlinks
            foundRow = Application.Match(hl.Address, listWS.Range("A2:A300"), 0)
            If IsNumeric(foundRow) Then
                listWS.Range("A2:A300").Cells(foundRow).Font.Color = vbGreen
                hl.Address = listWS.Range("B2:B300").Cells(foundRow).Value
            Else
                listWS.Cells(writeRow, "C").Value = currentWS.Name
                listWS.Cells(writeRow, "D").Value = hl.Address
                writeRow = writeRow + 1
            End If
        Next hl
    Next currentWS
End Sub
```

It is not necessary to activate each worksheet, as your "wks" already points to each sheet.

Comment: The above worked great in finding and replacing the hyperlinks on my shapes. How can I find the hyperlinks on the shapes that did not get changed because they where not on the B2:B300 list? They would be the hyperlinks that where 61 characters long.

Comment: I edited my answer to mark found / not found hyperlinks.

Comment: This method can be used to get a list of all of the hyperlinks on the worksheets or to troubleshoot errors by adjusting the A2:A300 and B2:B300 data ranges to a smaller sampling as changes take place ( i.e A2:A15 and B2:B15 would be edited hyperlinks needing changed) I reran 2-3 times until all hyperlinks where changed and my range was A2:A3 & B2:B3. The C and D columns then returned all of the hyperlinks for the shapes based on the worksheet name. You can verify your work easily as a simple sort of the column will spot any rouge links. This code answered my question completely!